# Updating images in File service/Azure using REST API-invalid header value 'Content-Length'

Tags: rest, azure, azure-files

I'm trying to upload the images to FILE SERVICE in Azure using REST API documentation specified here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range

visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="azure_cls_cpy">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputFile value="{!img}" filename="{!fileName}" fileSize="{!fileSize}" ></apex:inputFile>
    <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!createImage}"/><br/>
    <apex:messages />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my code, which is not working:

```
public void createImage(){
    string storageKey = 'xxxxStorageKeyxxxx';
    string storageName = '<storageName>';
    Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
    string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';

    string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-range:bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize)+'\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31\nx-ms-write:update';

    string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/<shareName>/<DirectoryName>/'+fileName+'\ncomp:range\ntimeout:20';
        string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\nstring.valueOf(fileSize)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
        system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

    Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
    Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); //StringToSign
    system.debug('oo-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac));
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
    req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length',string.valueOf(fileSize);
    req.setHeader('x-ms-range','bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize));        
    req.setHeader('x-ms-write','update');
    string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
    string authHeader =  'SharedKey biznussoftfiles'+':'+signature;

    req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
    req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<shareName>/<directoryName>/'+fileName+'?comp=range&timeout=20');
    req.setBodyAsBlob(img);              
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res;
    res = http.send(req);                
}
```

In my code, fileName,fileSize,img are the properties of the image i'm trying to upload(which are dynamic).

Here,I'm facing issue with Content-Length. Below is the error response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
<Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:0996d8a7-001a-0060-7376-2ce658000000
Time:2017-09-13T09:53:06.4734435Z</Message>
<HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
<HeaderValue>197844</HeaderValue>
 </Error>
```

Updated Note: Reverted the range back to 0-filesize() to avoid Invalid Range error.

Comment: I think your `CanonicalizedResource` is fine. I see some missing headers in `CanonicalizedHeaders`. It should include all request headers that start with `x-ms-`. I would strongly suggest that you read (rather cram :)), this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services. Once you understand the concepts outlined here, you should not face any problems with the REST API.

Comment: So you need to specify `Content-Length` header both in your request as well as consider the same when calculating stringToSign. Right now I am seeing that it is not included in your stringToSign. Please put that back and then edit the question accordingly.

Comment: What language are you using? Are there any HTTP client classes in that environment that you can use to help you build this request? It seems to me that there's a lot of complexity in your code that comes from putting together a HTTP request; there should be an easier way to do that.

Comment: @Rv1: But what language is your code sample in?

Comment: Taking a wild guess, can you try by removing this line completely `req.setHeader('Content-Length',string.valueOf(fileSize);`?

Comment: @GauravMantri It is a required field. Now, i made a change in x-ms-range as per documentation. Now, it is giving me some different error as 'Resource Not Found'.

Comment: Have you created the file already? For `Put Range` operation to work, a file must be present in storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, I created a file and tried to upload the file. It given me invalid Range error.So, I reverted back the range to 0-filesize() and run the code. Now,It is again giving me the Invalid Content Length error.

Comment: Hmmm....Can you tell what's the size of the file you created? Please edit the question and include the code for file creation as well.

Comment: Updated the full code(front end & method). I'm trying to upload the file of size 148kb

Comment: When I said `created the file`, I meant have you performed this operation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file? You need to do this before calling `createImage()`. In short, you would need to first create an empty file of 148KB and then push data in there.

Comment: As per document: "The Create File operation creates a new file or replaces a file. Note that calling Create File only initializes the file. To add content to a file, call the Put Range operation." So, i have used PUT RANGE operation but not CREATE FILE operation. Is there anything,I'm missing? Do i need to call both operations in a single transaction?

Comment: From here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range#remarks: `The Put Range operation writes a range of byte to a file. This operation can only be called on an existing file. It cannot be called to create a new file. Calling Put Range with a file name that does not currently exist returns status code 404 (Not Found).`

Comment: By using CreateFile documentation,I'm getting the same content-length error. I just performed that operation. Another point is: by the above code,i'm trying to update a file having the same name in azure storage. Both scenarios are throwing same error

Comment: :P .... REST API is not your friend today. Let me try to write some code later in the evening. I will use C#.

Comment: :D :D .. Yes, you're correct regarding REST API. Thank you for your time. I've posted createFile service question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195457/uploading-new-images-to-azure-fileservice-using-createfile-service        You can have a look in your free time @GauravMantri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have seen the issue sooner :). Essentially the issue was with your `x-ms-range` header. Because it starts from `0`, the ending value should be the `length of the image - 1`. Once you do that, the code should work just fine.

Please see the code below:

```
public class azure_cls_cpy {
    public string fileName {get; set;}
    public integer fileSize {get; set;}
    public blob img {get; set;}

    public void createImage(){
        string storageKey = 'account-key';
        string storageName = 'account-name';
        string shareName = 'share-name';
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
        string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';
        system.debug('formattedDate--'+formattedDate);
        system.debug('fileSize--'+fileSize);
        string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-range:bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize-1)+'\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31\nx-ms-write:update';

        string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/' + shareName + '/' +fileName + '\ncomp:range';
        string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n' + string.valueOf(fileSize) + '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
        system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

        system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

        Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
        Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
        req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
        req.setHeader('x-ms-range','bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize-1));
        req.setHeader('x-ms-write','update');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', string.valueOf(fileSize));
        string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
        string authHeader =  'SharedKey ' + storageName +':'+signature;
        req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + storageName + '.file.core.windows.net/' + shareName + '/' + fileName + '?comp=range');
        req.setBodyAsBlob(img);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res;
        res = http.send(req);     
        string responseBody = res.getBody();
        system.debug('responseBody--'+responseBody);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had a hit over this scenario. In such cases, its throwing 'ResourceNotFound' exception

Comment: Please see my comment in your other question regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting states that Content-Length value is unexpected. Likely your payload you are sending does not match 2224 bytes. Check whether setBodyAsBlob really sends 2224 byte of data. You can verify this capturing packets on a tool like WireShark.

Comment: Any help @sguler. I have verified the bytes sending in the request by converting the blob to EncodingUtil.base64Encode. It is working fine. Any other idea

Comment: Sorry - no idea. I have had the exact same error happening to me in Java, where the bytes sent wouldn't match the content-length. Even if it is 1 byte off, the server will fail your request. I would strongly suggest you to actually check the bytes on the wire from Fiddler or WireShark. Btw - why don't you use the existing Azure Storage Client Libraries instead ?

Comment: In salesforce, there is no option to use existing libraries like java. I'm unaware of Fiddler or wireshark functionality. Btw- how you resolved the byte range difference issue in java?