# Uploading new images to Azure FileService using 'CREATEFILE' service

Tags: rest, azure

I'm trying to upload the images to FILE SERVICE in Azure using REST API(CREATE FILE) documentation specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

Here is my code, which is not working:

```
public class azure_cls_cpy {
    public string fileName {get; set;}
    public integer fileSize {get; set;}
    public blob img {get; set;}

    public void createImage(){
        string storageKey = 'account-key';
        string storageName = 'account-name';
        string shareName = 'share-name';
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
        string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';
        system.debug('formattedDate--'+formattedDate);
        system.debug('fileSize--'+fileSize);
        integer imageSize = img.size();
        system.debug('imageSize--'+imageSize);
        string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-content-length:'+string.valueOf(fileSize)+'\nx-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31';

        string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/' + shareName + '/' +fileName;
        string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n\n\nimage/png\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
        system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

        Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
        Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
        req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
        req.setHeader('x-ms-content-length',string.valueOf(fileSize));
        req.setHeader('x-ms-type','file');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','image/png');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
        string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
        string authHeader =  'SharedKey ' + storageName +':'+signature;
        req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + storageName + '.file.core.windows.net/' + shareName + '/'+fileName);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res;
        res = http.send(req);     
        string responseBody = res.getBody();
        system.debug('responseBody--'+responseBody);
    createImage_Put();
    }
}

//Put Range Operation
public void createImage_Put(){

    string storageKey = 'xxxxstorageKeyxxxx';
    string storageName = '<storageName>';
    Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
    string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';        
    string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-range:bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize)+'\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31\nx-ms-write:update';
    string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/<shareName>/'+fileName+'\ncomp:range';
    string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n'+string.valueOf(fileSize)+'\n\nimage/png\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
    system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

    Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
    Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
    req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length',string.valueOf(fileSize));
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','image/png');
    req.setHeader('x-ms-range','bytes=0-'+string.valueOf(fileSize));
    req.setHeader('x-ms-write','update');
    string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
    string authHeader =  'SharedKey '+ storageName+':'+signature;
    req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
    req.setEndpoint('https://storageName.file.core.windows.net/<shareName>/'+fileName+'?comp=range');
    req.setBodyAsBlob(img);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res;
    res = http.send(req);  
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.info,'responseBody of PutRange operation--'+res.getBody()));
}
}
```

In my code, fileName,fileSize,img are the properties of the image i'm trying to upload(which are dynamic).

Here,I'm facing issue with from createImage_Put (PUT RANGE Operation). Below is the error response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
<Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:0996d8a7-001a-0060-7376-2ce658000000
Time:2017-09-13T09:53:06.4734435Z</Message>
<HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
<HeaderValue>197844</HeaderValue>
 </Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code.

- Because you're simply creating the file, you need not specify the content length of the file in `StringToSign`. It should be empty.
- Again because you're creating an empty file, you should not send file data in request body. It should be empty.

Based on these, please see the code below. I was able to run this code and it successfully created an empty file.

```
public class azure_cls_cpy {
    public string fileName {get; set;}
    public integer fileSize {get; set;}
    public blob img {get; set;}

    public void createImage(){
        string storageKey = 'account-key';
        string storageName = 'account-name';
        string shareName = 'share-name';
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
        string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';
        system.debug('formattedDate--'+formattedDate);
        system.debug('fileSize--'+fileSize);
        integer imageSize = img.size();
        system.debug('imageSize--'+imageSize);
        string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-content-length:'+string.valueOf(fileSize)+'\nx-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31';

        string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/' + shareName + '/' +fileName;
        string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n\n\nimage/png\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
        system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

        Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
        Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
        req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
        req.setHeader('x-ms-content-length',string.valueOf(fileSize));
        req.setHeader('x-ms-type','file');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','image/png');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
        string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
        string authHeader =  'SharedKey ' + storageName +':'+signature;
        req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + storageName + '.file.core.windows.net/' + shareName + '/'+fileName);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res;
        res = http.send(req);     
        string responseBody = res.getBody();
        system.debug('responseBody--'+responseBody);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Empty file is creating successfully. But,how are we going to add the exact image?

Comment: So it is going to be a 2 step process. In first step, you will create an empty file of the size that you're trying to upload i.e. perform "Create File" REST API operation and in the next step you will set data in that file i.e. perform "Put Range" REST API operation.

Comment: I've called 2 REST calls, but i find 'Invalid Range error' if i provide range 0-size-1. If i give original range i'm getting invalid content length error

Comment: Please edit your question and include the latest code or ask a new question.

Comment: I've updated the code. I'm put range operation after createFile operation.

Comment: In your `createImage_Put()`, please change the range header value. It should be from `0` to `file size - 1`.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. It may not hurt to ask a separate question. Please note that there's no anonymous access to files in file storage. So you can't do `<img src="file-url">` in your code.

Comment: Sorry for asking a different and unclear question.Please bare with me. I'll will elaborate my question: I'm making GETFILE() service. I'm able to get the response from azure. But, inorder to display/download the image in an external system is there any specified tag available in response which i can use?

Comment: Nope. You would need to download the file in an external system. You will again be making REST API call to download the file and save it in that external system. I think we should not ask more questions in comments here. If you have additional question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I've created new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216172/displaying-images-of-file-service-from-azure-in-external-system-rest-api